# Why won't I automatically login to CrossValidated when already in StackOverflow?

Tags: support

When I login to StackOverflow and switch to have a look at CrossValidated, I need to login again.

If I first go to CrossValidated, I am already online at StackOverflow automatically.

If I login to StackExchange I am also online at both sites directly.

It's not a big deal, I can always login at CrossValidated (or StackExchange) but still wanted to know if I overlooked a checkmark somewhere (about shared login). Any ideas?

---

**Edit**

To clarify the different scenarios:

**Scenario A**

1st.: Login at stackoverflow.com:

→ new login needed at stats.stackexchange.com

→ new login needed at tex.stackexchange.com

→ automatically logged in at askubuntu.com

**Scenario B**

1st.: Login at stats.stackexchange.com:

→ automatically logged in at stackoverflow.com

→ automatically logged in at tex.stackexchange.com

→ automatically logged in at askubuntu.com

**Scenario C:**

1st.: Login at stackexchange.com:

→ automatically logged in at stackoverflow.com

→ automatically logged in at stats.stackexchange.com

→ automatically logged in at tex.stackexchange.com

→ automatically logged in at askubuntu.com

It is noteworthy that I can see my sites (and reputation) in the drop down menu, even though not online in all sites. In the following screenshot I am logged in (only) to stackoverflow.com, but get also *notifications (rep change)* from CrossValidated. If I click on CrossValidated (or TeX-LaTeX), I am redirected to the corresponding login site. This is what I previously described as *Scenario A*.

[image]

Comment: Because they're on different domains. You should automatically be logged in to every site on the `stackexchange.com` domain, though.

Comment: @JNat However, I can see that I login automatically to ubuntu.stackexchange, but not tex.stackexchange (or CV) when first logged to stackoverflow. Is there like a «team»  of sites in a common domain, where other do not share access?

Comment: Wait, let me clarify, since I missed a few important words on that previous comment. You should automatically be logged in to every site on the `stackexchange.com` domain _after you've logged in to CV, though. Is that not what you're describing? Do you need to log in to CV _every single time_ you come here, even if you didn't log out, and use the same machine?

Comment: [This post](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/260153/global-auth-is-dead-long-live-universal-login) may also be of help in understanding how the log in system works.

Comment: No. The part I don't understand is: I need to login to CV *even though I am first online at stackoverflow*, **but** I *do not* need to login to stackoverflow if I am first online at CV. In all cases I speak from being completely offline (logged off from all sites: upper-left menu).

Comment: @JNat Thanks for the link! It seems like the important part for my question is
> stackoverflow.com, superuser.com, and other Q&A sites with their own domains will still use the old flow.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure, so I've asked Adam to have a look at this post himself. He should be able to clarify any withstanding doubts.

Comment: Can you walk me through the exact steps you're taking, please? Including which domain you're on when you do. e.g. when you say "log in to StackExchange", do you mean you log in on stackexchange.com or on a q&a subdomain like stats.stackexchange.com?

Comment: @Adam I edited the question to try and be more precise, hope it's clearer now.